# logstash or filebeat to create multiple output files from tomcat log

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat, logstash-configuration

I need to parse a tomcat log file and output it into several output files.

Each file is the result of a certain filter that will pick certain entries in the tomcat file that match a series of regexes or other transformation rule.

Currently I am doing this using a python script but it is not very flexible.
Is there a configurable tool for doing this?

I have looked into filebeat and logstash [none of which I am very familiar with] but it is not clear if it is possible to configure them to map a single input file into multiple output files each with a different filter/grok set of expressions.

Is it possible to achieve this with filebeat/logstash?

Comment: All log files are at the same servers ?

Comment: Yes all on the same servers

Comment: below my response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all logs files are on the same servers you dont need Filebeat. Logstash can do the work.

Here an example of what your config logstash can look like.
In input you have you tomcat log file and you have multi output (json) depend of loglevel once logs have been parsed.

The grok is also an example you must define your own grok pattern depend on your log format.

```
input { 
 file {
    path => "/var/log/tomcat.log"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} - %{POSTFIX_SESSIONID:sessionId}: %{GREEDYDATA:messageText}" }
  }
}

output {
  if [loglevel] == "info" {
     file {
       codec => "json"
       path => "/var/log/tomcat_info_parsed.log"
     }
  }
  
  if [loglevel] == "warning" {
     file {
       codec => "json"
       path => "/var/log/tomcat_warning_parsed.log"
     }
  }
}
```